# Resource (resx) from an external resources assembly - Disk or Memory IO?

Tags: .net, resources, io

In .Net, When I fetch a resource from a resx in an external resources assembly - does this involve a fetch from Disk or Memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assemblies are loaded memmapped.

So the first time you access it it will be a Disk IO. Subsequent calls to the assembly resources will be Memory IO unless the relevant part was not (yet) loaded from disk.

BTW: This is implementation specific. So no guarantee it will always be like this. But it is for Mono and for MS.Net.